# Github pages debug tools or debug pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

When setting up jekyll/liquid based Github pages I started to wonder about the precise content of `site`, and also wanted some debug views. So I added a set of generated debug pages, see [here](https://wfjm.github.io/debug/). They give a lot of information about `site` and also `site.github`. The source is [here](https://github.com/wfjm/wfjm.github.io/tree/master/debug).

With hindsight I wonder whether I re-invented the wheel, whether there are some build-in tools like this ?

Comment: You can try {{ var | inspect }}

Comment: @DavidJacquel: I wanted something easy to read. I did look into `inspect`, but that gives a lot of internal detail which I wasn't after. In addition, I couldn't find documentation, [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) is stated that it exists, but not what the output means. I also tried `jsonify`, but even that is tedious to understand in case of a big object like `site`. So I ended up in writing [all the liquid code](https://github.com/wfjm/wfjm.github.io/tree/master/debug) to get a easy to grasp output.